# Should I use Berry boot or 2 SD cards?

Tags: retropie, berryboot, multiboot

Would it be better to swap SD cards to switch from Retropie to Raspbian, etc. or use Berry boot on same SD card and store Roms on my network or USB stick? Also, does anyone have experience using network or USB storage for Retropie roms?  Any recommendations?

Comment: Hello and welcome -- What do you mean by `store Roms on my network or USB stick?`? -- `Should I use Berry boot or 2 SD cards?` Simple answer, no. It gives you time and not that much stable. Therefore follow the easiest way.